# How do I alter my existing table to create a range partition in Oracle

Tags: oracle, create-table, alter-table, partition

I have existing table which has 10 years of data (I have taken dump).

I would like to Range partition the existing table on one date key column within the table.

Most of the examples I see are with `CREATE TABLE..PARTITION BY RANGE...` to add new partitions. But my table is existing table.

I assume I need some `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
PARTITION BY RANGE(CREATED_DATE)
 PARTITION JAN16 VALUES LESS THAN (01-02-2016),
 PARTITION FEB16 VALUES LESS THAN (01-03-2016) AND GREATER THAN(31-01-2016),//OR?
 PARTITION MAR16 VALUES BETWEEN (01-03-2016) AND (31-03-2016),  //OR?
```

Two questions..

1. Do I need Alter statement to add partitioning mechanism or need to work with create statement?
2. What is the proper syntax for keeping each partition having only ONE MONTH data.

Comment: You can not `alter` a table to be partitioned. You need to drop and re-create it. You can only use `alter` to _add_ partitions to a table that is _already_ partitioned

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `You can not alter a table to be partitioned` actually you can :)

Comment: @lad2025: but only with `dbms_redefinition` which is not  exactly an `alter` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was referring to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451221/5070879), not DBMS_REDEFINITION.

Comment: Well, that wasn't possible in 2016 when I wrote the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beacuse your table non-partitioned you have two options:

1. Export data, drop table, create new patitioned table, import data.
2. Use split then exchange partition method. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition

Also, if you want new partition per month read about SET INTERVAL. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tst
   (col_date DATE)
 PARTITION BY RANGE (col_date) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(PARTITION col_date_min VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Oracle 12c Release 2` you could use single `ALTER` to convert non-partitioned table to partitioned one (this is one way trip):

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab ( a NUMBER(38,0), b NUMBER(38,0)); 

ALTER TABLE MY_TAB MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (a) INTERVAL (1000) (   
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)) ONLINE;
```

You could convert indexes too, adding:

```
update indexes (index_name [local/global]);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dddc997829b0a41ad3722920aee8b639)**

Comment: When i runt he above sql, It throws an error as "Invalid Partition name"

Comment: @TejuMB You have lower version than 12R2 demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dddc997829b0a41ad3722920aee8b639