# oracle how to alter table add partition by range interval

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have searched a lot but i have found nothing about how to
add a range partition to an existing table

```
alter table myuser.mytable
add PARTITION  BY RANGE (mynumber) INTERVAL (1)
( PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (108))
```

that gives me ORA:14150 error, SUBPARTITON keyword is missing,
but i dont want to give subpartition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alter my existing table to create a range partition in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932771/how-do-i-alter-my-existing-table-to-create-a-range-partition-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** On 19c and 12cR2 this can be done using the `MODIFY` Clause of `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE myuser.mytable MODIFY
PARTITION  BY RANGE (mynumber) INTERVAL (1)
( PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (108)
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (109))  
ONLINE
UPDATE INDEXES
```

[See this from Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5)

**PRIOR To 19c or 12cR2:**

If your existing Table is Non-Partitioned you will have to:

1. `CREATE` a new `TABLE` with `partition` definitions. Lets call this table `MYTABLE_NEW`
2. `INSERT` into `MYTABLE_NEW` all data from `MYTABLE`
3. `RENAME` `MYTABLE` to `MYTABLE_OLD`
4. `RENAME` `MYTABLE_NEW` to `MYTABLE`
5. `DROP` `MYTABLE_OLD`

**OR**

`dbms_redefinition` can also be used

[See this from AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:869096700346654484)

[Also see this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507336/how-to-add-interval-partitions-to-an-existing-table-in-oracle)