# Oracle table and index partitioning - risk and disadvantages

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, relational-database, database-performance, partitioning

I have large unpartitioned tables in the database (100GB+), and to be able to improve performance I think about partitioning them, or maybe just indexes. Data comes in on regularly basis, and is selected by dates, so I think range partitioning by month of creation date would be good opion.

I am reading about [oracle table and index partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm), and it look quite promising.
But I have two questions, for which I can not find answers (I think my google skills are going down).

First one is:

What are risk and disadvantages of creating partitioned tables and indexes in oracle, in particular on such large and alive tables? Is there something that I should know about?

Second:

How to create partition on existing and unpartitioned table or index?

Comment: I would think that partitioning over time would not be very risky.  You should try partitioning by month, quarter, year, or some other interval.  You can ETL the oldest ones to your reporting and archive store; it's a natural history partition.

Comment: for the second:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890495/oracle-how-to-alter-table-add-partition-by-range-interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Besides the outage (see below) needed to partition your data, the main risk I see is that if you decide to partition your table and indexes, with local indexes, your performance will not be great for queries not relying on the partition key (date). But you can use global indexes in that case, and go back to similar performances.
2. The simplest way to create a partitioned table from an unpartitioned one, by far, is to use [create table as select](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm) with a new name and all the partition storage detail, delete the unpartitioned table and renamed the new table as the old one. Obviously, this requires careful preparation, and an outage that can last a few minutes :)